# React-Modal "Cannot Read Property of State of Null" Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a react-redux app where after a citation is generated the user has the option to save the citation to a separate list.  I import Modal from 'react-modal' and then dispatch to the store information about the citation.  It then redirects me to the citation list successfully.  However, if I go to add another citation and click one of the header buttons (one going home or the other going to the citation list) *before* triggering the Modal, then I get the error "Cannot read property of state of null."  If I remove the modal, then I do not get the error so I know it is related to the modal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<SaveModal
  fullCitation={this.state.fullCitation}
  saveCitation={this.state.saveCitation}
  handleClearSaveCitation={this.handleClearSaveCitation}
  history={this.props.history}
  createdAt={this.state.createdAt}
  type={this.state.type} 
  note={this.state.note}
  dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
  handleAddType={this.handleAddType}
  handleAddNote={this.handleAddNote}
/>

import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addCitation } from '../actions/citations';

const SaveModal = (props) => (
  <Modal
    isOpen={props.saveCitation}
    onRequestClose={props.handleClearSaveCitation}
    contentLabel="SaveModal"
    closeTimeoutMS={200}
    className="modal"
  >
    <h3>{props.fullCitation}</h3>
    <h3>{props.createdAt}</h3>
    <input 
      autoFocus 
      className="text-input" 
      type="text" 
      id="type" 
      placeholder="Add Type (Optional)"
      onChange={props.handleAddType}
    />
    <textarea
      id="textarea"
      className="text-input" 
      placeholder="Add Note (Optional)"
      onChange={props.handleAddNote}
    >
    </textarea>
    <button 
      className="button"
      onClick={() => {
        props.dispatch(addCitation({ 
          fullCitation: props.fullCitation, 
          createdAt: props.createdAt, 
          type: props.type, 
          note: props.note 
        }));
        props.history.push('/CitationList');
      }}
    >Save</button>
  </Modal>
);

export default connect()(SaveModal);
```

UPDATE:

The state is defined in the parent component and then passed down to Modal.  A bunch of methods follow that manipulate the state before it is passed down to child components such as AddParties.

```
import React from 'react';
import term from '../term';
import AddParties from '../components/AddParties';
import AddOhioVolume from '../components/AddOhioVolume';
import AddRegionalVolume from '../components/AddRegionalVolume';
import AddYear from '../components/AddYear';
import AddPinpoint from '../components/AddPinpoint';
import AddWebcite from '../components/AddWebcite';
import CiteCase from '../components/CiteCase';
import Citation from '../components/Citation';
import RemoveCitation from '../components/RemoveCitation';
import CopyCitation from '../components/CopyCitation';
import SaveCitation from '../components/SaveCitation';
import moment from 'moment';
import SaveModal from '../components/SaveModal';


export default class SupremePost extends React.Component {
  state = {
    partyOne: "",
    partyTwo: "", 
    ohioVolume: "",
    ohioReporter: "",
    ohioFirstPage: "",
    regionalVolume: "",
    regionalReporter: "",
    regionalFirstPage: "",
    year: "",
    pinpointNumber: "",
    pinpointDisplay: "",
    webcite: "",
    parties: "",
    citation: "",
    fullCitation: "",
    createdAt: "",
    saveCitation: false,
    type: "None",
    note: "None"
  };
```

Comment: I guess Redux out of the box only works with Stateful component and you are using a stateless component here. Try making it stateful (extends component) and see if it works?

Comment: The first message below the "property state of null" is Modal.componentWillUnmount (Modal.js:119)

I think that may have something to do with it.  It does not make sense that I cannot route to other pages while I am on a page with Modal.  Everything else works in terms of viewing the state and seeing the proper dispatch to the store when I am actually using the modal.

Comment: BUT WHERE is your state defined? Where is eg. this.state.note. Redux are props shared globally, and state is local. In provided code state is null.

Comment: This is state in `SupremePost` but `SaveModal` compoment is type of `Modal`. How do you inherit this state form `SupremePost`?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, the code above shows how the state is passed in as props to the Modal

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I was using an outdated version of react-modal.  I updated it, and now I have no further issues.